# How do you set up a custom domain with CNAME on Heroku without messing up email service?

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I have a Rails app uploaded to Heroku and I'd like to use it for a custom domain name. I also have email for this domain name on 1and1 where I registered it and it's been in use and needs to remain working. I tried following [this tutorial](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/10/7/heroku_casts_setting_up_custom_domains/) but it recommends using naked domains which Heroku is strongly discouraging. If I shouldn't use naked domains (is that better?), how do I use CNAME instead while still keeping the email functional?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a CNAME record for each "hostname" you want to use.  For example, if you want to use **www.yourdomain.com** you would need to add a CNAME record to your DNS server(service) that maps www -> your-app-name.heroku.com.

Your DNS servers will then direct all requests for www.yourdomain.com to DNS name you-app-name.heroku.com and Heroku's DNS handles the mapping to IP address.

Comment: The problem with adding a Cname is it gets rid of 1and1 email address usage.

Comment: That's a fault with 1&1 then - probably best to find a DNS host that doesn't impose that limitation which is trying to force you to use their services.